# when anonymous access removed from artifactory hosting a bower package, unable to do "bower install" with credentials in .bowerrc

Tags: bower, artifactory, credentials, unauthorized

My javascript project has a bower.json with a dependency like this:

```
...
"dependencies":{
...
"dep_name":"https://artifactory.corp.company.com/artifactory/path/to/bower/package.tar.gz",
...
}
...
```

with this "bower install" fails with EHTTP Status code 401 (Unauthorized)

Changing the above to include credentials allows "bower install" to succeed:

```
"dependencies":{
...
"dep_name":"https://<username>:<password>@artifactory.corp.company.com/artifactory/path/to/bower/package.tar.gz",
...
}
```

However, bower.json is part of git tracked files and also every developer will have individual credentials. Hence, ideal place for credentials will be ~/.bowerrc file (it will be outside the project folder and therefore not tracked by git and will be developer specific).

Problem is, I do not know how to get this done.
Referred to following links with no luck:

[jFrog documentation](https://www.jfrog.com/confluence/display/RTF4X/Bower+Repositories)
[sonatype documentation](https://help.sonatype.com/repomanager3/bower-repositories)

I do not wish to host private registry.

Comment: The [documentation](https://www.jfrog.com/confluence/display/RTF4X/Bower+Repositories#BowerRepositories-UsingBowerVersion1.5andabove) exactly specifies how to achieve this -  are you missing some details..?

Comment: @danf Thanks for trying to help. I believe I have added a link to the same (similar) JFrog documentation in my question and mentioned that solution in the documentation works (i.e embedding username and password in the dependency url in bower.json). I have also mentioned why this is not suitable for my scenario. Does the documentation talk about how to solve by doing something outside of bower.json (for example, in ~/.bowerrc file)? I could not find that.

Comment: I'm not sure I follow... the doc I linked to deals with the `.bowerrc` file which is the standard way to do registry auth (at least as far as I know), I also use it myself...

Comment: Also, if you simply use the [Set Me Up](https://www.jfrog.com/confluence/display/RTF/General+Information#GeneralInformation-SetMeUp) feature its gonna give you the exact snippet you should paste in the `.bowerrc` file